# Powershell - Select a specific word from text

Tags: powershell

I'm still very much learning Powershell and I'm a bit lost regarding a command to use.
I have this

```
docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com
```

and I want to select PASSWORD.
Ideally, I would like this PASSWORD to get into a file, and use it after (but that I can do).

I am lost on what command to use. I know awk '{print $6}' would work but I need the powershell as I'm using a windows machine.

I know it's a really simple question, I have been reading answers, but I am just confused by the different parameters, and the different ways by different people and well, Powershell is wonderful but I'm still learning.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default field separator(s) in `awk` is whitespace, so we can do the same in PowerShell and then grab the 6<sup>th</sup> resulting substring.

For this, we can use the `-split` regex operator - it supports the following syntaxes:

```
[strings] -split [pattern]
```

or

```
-split [strings]
```

When used as in the second example above, it defaults to splitting on whitespace just like `awk`:

```
-split "docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com"
```

If we wrap the expression in `@()`, we can index into it:

```
$Password = @(
  -split "docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com"
)[5]
```

or we can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to grab it:

```
$Password = -split "docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com" |Select-Object -Index 5
```

---

If, however, we always want to grab the substring immediately after `-p` instead of whatever the 6<sup>th</sup> string is, we could use the `-replace` regex operator instead:

```
$string = "docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com"
$string -replace '^.*-p\s+(\S+).*$','$1'
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with -split @(Get-Content -Path FILEPATH |Select-Object -Index 5 | Out-File -FilePath FILEPATH. I'm sure that's not the most efficient but it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this more complex :) I just used simple regexp, but you can make it better :)

```
$x = "docker login -u AWS -p PApSSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com "
$x -match "(\-p[a-z0-9 ]*\-e)"
$matches[1] -replace '(\-p) ([a-z0-9 ]*) (\-e)' , ' $2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using a Regular Expression,
here with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$string = 'docker login -u AWS -p PASSWORD -e none number.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com'
if ($string -match '(?<=-p\s+).*(?=\s+-e)'){
    $Password = $Matches.Value
} else {
    "No password found"
}
```